# How to fix {"code":415,"message":"Unsupported media type"} when sending request to yandex api in PHP?

Tags: php, post, yandex

Instead of returning the translated result, I get: 
{"code":415,"message":"Unsupported media type"}

```
$key = 'removedForQuestion,butIThinkItWorks';
$tr = new Trnsl($key);

$result = $tr->translate('Hello how are you','en-es');
echo $result;
```

Here is a link to the class Trnsl: https://github.com/igor-tv/yandex_translate/blob/master/src/Trnsl.php

I am not sure why this is not working.

Comment: Your link does not work, but the code states that the content type is not supported. Have you tried another [Version](https://github.com/yandex-php/translate-api)?

Comment: I fixed the link. @KHansen

Comment: Never mind, I made it work using the link you sent. Thank you so much!